# fulfill an empty dataframe with common index values from another Daframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have a daframe with a series of period 1 month and frequency one second.

The problem the time step between records is not always 1 second.

```
time                c1  c2
2013-01-01 00:00:01 5   3
2013-01-01 00:00:03 7   2
2013-01-01 00:00:04 1   5
2013-01-01 00:00:05 4   3
2013-01-01 00:00:06 5   6
2013-01-01 00:00:09 4   2
2013-01-01 00:00:10 7   8
```

Then I want to create an empty dataframe with the same columns and for the whole period corrected. That means with as many records as seconds has a month. This empty dataframe is fulfilled in principle with nan values:

```
time                c1  c2
2013-01-01 00:00:01 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:02 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:03 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:04 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:05 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:06 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:07 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:08 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:09 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:10 nan nan
```

Then compare both, and fulfill the empty one, with the common rows with my first dataframe. The non-common should remain with nan values.

```
time                c1  c2
2013-01-01 00:00:01 5   3
2013-01-01 00:00:02 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:03 7   2
2013-01-01 00:00:04 1   5
2013-01-01 00:00:05 4   3
2013-01-01 00:00:06 5   6
2013-01-01 00:00:07 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:08 nan nan
2013-01-01 00:00:09 4   2
2013-01-01 00:00:10 7   8
```

My try:

```
#Read from a file the first dataframe
df1=pd.read_table(fin,parse_dates=0],names=ch,index_col=0,header=0,decimal='.',skiprows=c)
#create an empty dataframe 
N=86400 * 31#seconds per month
index=pd.date_range(df1.index[0], periods=N-1, freq='1s')
df2=pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=df1.columns)
```

Now I try with merge or concat but without the expected result:

```
df2.merge(df1, how='outer')
pd.concat([df2,df1], axis=0, join='outer')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a second dataframe. If you call [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) without a `fill_method`, it will store `NaN`s for the missing periods:

```
df.resample("s").max()
Out[62]: 
                      c1   c2
time                         
2013-01-01 00:00:01  5.0  3.0
2013-01-01 00:00:02  NaN  NaN
2013-01-01 00:00:03  7.0  2.0
2013-01-01 00:00:04  1.0  5.0
2013-01-01 00:00:05  4.0  3.0
2013-01-01 00:00:06  5.0  6.0
2013-01-01 00:00:07  NaN  NaN
2013-01-01 00:00:08  NaN  NaN
2013-01-01 00:00:09  4.0  2.0
2013-01-01 00:00:10  7.0  8.0
```

`max()` here is just an arbitrary method so that it returns a dataframe. You can replace it with mean, min etc. assuming you have no duplicates. If you have duplicates, they will be aggregated by that function.

As Paul H suggested in the comments, you can use `df.resample("s").asfreq()` without any aggregation. It skips an unnecessary step of aggregation so it is probably more efficient. It will raise an error if you have duplicate values in the index.

Comment: I want to keep the common values as they are, not to resample them

Comment: @gis20 since the frequencies are the same, you should get the common values as they are. Is there any difference?

Comment: `df.resample("s").asfreq()` will blindly upsample the data without applying any sort of reduction function/

Answer (score 0):

You need to `reindex` the dataframe.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_table(filename, **options)
N = 86400 * 31 #seconds per month
dates = pandas.date_range(df.index[0], periods=N-1, freq='1s')
df = df.reindex(dates)
```

Here's a reproducible demonstration:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data={'A': range(0, 10), 'B': range(0, 20, 2)},
    index=pandas.date_range('2012-01-01', freq='2s', periods=10)
).reindex(pandas.date_range('2012-01-01', freq='1s', periods=25))

print(df)

                       A     B
2012-01-01 00:00:00  0.0   0.0
2012-01-01 00:00:01  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:02  1.0   2.0
2012-01-01 00:00:03  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:04  2.0   4.0
2012-01-01 00:00:05  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:06  3.0   6.0
2012-01-01 00:00:07  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:08  4.0   8.0
2012-01-01 00:00:09  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:10  5.0  10.0
2012-01-01 00:00:11  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:12  6.0  12.0
2012-01-01 00:00:13  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:14  7.0  14.0
2012-01-01 00:00:15  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:16  8.0  16.0
2012-01-01 00:00:17  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:18  9.0  18.0
2012-01-01 00:00:19  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:20  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:21  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:22  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:23  NaN   NaN
2012-01-01 00:00:24  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Does not work.*** ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @gis20 see my edits. I can't help you anymore than that without a reproducible example that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you already set up the indexes in the "nan" data frame, I think you should be able to just use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). [Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) is a really important thing to master when using Pandas. It will save you a whole lot of time, make your code a lot cleaner and can really improve your performance.

Careful though, the indexes and columns have to be the same for the trick below to work as is.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df1
          A         B         C
0  0.171502  0.258416  0.118326
1  0.215456  0.462122  0.858173
2  0.373549  0.946400  0.579845
3  0.606289  0.289552  0.473658
4  0.885899  0.783747  0.089975
5  0.674208  0.639710  0.105642
6  0.404775  0.541389  0.268101
7  0.374609  0.693916  0.743575
8  0.074773  0.150072  0.135555
9  0.230431  0.202417  0.466538

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(15), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df2
     A   B   C
0  NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN NaN
5  NaN NaN NaN
6  NaN NaN NaN
7  NaN NaN NaN
8  NaN NaN NaN
9  NaN NaN NaN
10 NaN NaN NaN
11 NaN NaN NaN
12 NaN NaN NaN
13 NaN NaN NaN
14 NaN NaN NaN

>>> df2.loc[df1.index] = df1    # This is where the magic happens
>>> df2
           A         B         C
0   0.171502  0.258416  0.118326
1   0.215456  0.462122  0.858173
2   0.373549  0.946400  0.579845
3   0.606289  0.289552  0.473658
4   0.885899  0.783747  0.089975
5   0.674208  0.639710  0.105642
6   0.404775  0.541389  0.268101
7   0.374609  0.693916  0.743575
8   0.074773  0.150072  0.135555
9   0.230431  0.202417  0.466538
10       NaN       NaN       NaN
11       NaN       NaN       NaN
12       NaN       NaN       NaN
13       NaN       NaN       NaN
14       NaN       NaN       NaN
```