# No attribute error when resampling

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
        date    count
0   2012-03-23  2
1   2012-03-25  1
2   2012-03-26  1
3   2012-03-27  1
4   2012-03-28  3
5   2012-04-05  2
6   2012-04-06  1
7   2012-04-08  2
8   2012-04-10  1
9   2012-04-11  1
```

I am trying to get a daterange from the date column by using

```
df.set_index('date').resample('D').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

But this results in

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Even though the date column as no strings in it.

Any idea what is casuing the error?

Comment: `resample('D')` is not returning a dataframe. When you call `fillna` on that object I guess it tries to do that on indices. Do you have duplicate dates? If yes, how do you plan on handling them (e.g. taking the mean, max etc.)?

Comment: Looks like I have to use `resample('D').mean()` now.  Weird

Comment: I checked again and `fillna` method of resample expects a method argument. It's different from `df.fillna` so if you pass 0 it accepts it as a method rather than a value. @PaulH suggested using `df.resample("D").asfreq()` on another post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36775460/2285236

Comment: FYI, I just fixed this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/797baf9f2e7af17c6a3287a2465211dc5988605e as is a bug in 0.18.0